# Resolve operator conflicts on similar generic types

Tags: f#

I'm using a third party library (Sauve.IO) which defines the standard bind operator >>= :

```
 val inline (>>=) : first:('T -> Async<'U option>) -> second:('U -> Async<'V option>) -> input:'T -> Async<'V option>
```

I also have an internal library that would also like to define the operator over the type signature

```
Async<Response<'a>> -> ('a -> Async<Response<'b>>) -> Async<Response<'b>>
```

What is the cleanest way to use these two functions in the same namespace/module without running afoul of the restriction on overloading inline functions ?

Comment: It *may* be easier with a [Computation Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx) and its `Bind` method. Here's an example where [`>>=`](https://github.com/fsprojects/Chessie/blob/9b5277f5b611139323fbe71d3efdb72d7ac1c430/src/Chessie/ErrorHandling.fs#L98) is [used in `Bind` method](https://github.com/fsprojects/Chessie/blob/9b5277f5b611139323fbe71d3efdb72d7ac1c430/src/Chessie/ErrorHandling.fs#L172), and [here's a way to use it afterwards](https://github.com/fsprojects/Chessie/blob/9b5277f5b611139323fbe71d3efdb72d7ac1c430/tests/Chessie.Tests/NightClubs.fs#L45-L53).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to leverage F#'s statically resolved ad-hoc polymorphism: hide the qualified operator invocation behind a separate, overloaded operator; then define yet another, inlined operator for actual use.

```
type Foo = Foo with
    static member ($) (_ : Foo, first : _ -> Async<_ option>) =
        fun second value -> Module1.(>>=) first second value 
    static member ($) (_ : Foo, arg1 : Async<Response<_>>) =
        Module2.(>>=) arg1

let inline (>>=) arg1 arg2 = (Foo $ arg1) arg2
```

Answer (score 3):

How about renaming Suave's operator to some other infix operator?

```
let (>=>) = Suave.(>>=)
```

Judging from the signature, it looks like it is not bind anyway,
but actually [Kleisli composition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-).

Answer (score 0):

Do both operators have the same name `(>>=)` ?
If so I assume that Suave's operator came with it's own module or namespace?
In this case you can qualify their operator appending their module/namespace name like this `Suave.(>>=)` but in this case you have to call it as usual function. Here is simplified example:

```
module Suave =
    let inline (>>=) a b = a + 2 * b 


module Mine = 
    open Suave
    let (>>=) a b = a - 3 * b 

    let r1 = Suave.(>>=) 1 3 
    let r2 = 1 >>= 3
```

Result:

```
  val r1 : int = 7
  val r2 : int = -8
```

Comment: Both operators do have the same name. That's true about the qualified access, I was hoping I could find a way to use both as infix operators for stylistic reasons. There doesn't appear to be a legal way to overload inline operators though :-(

Current approach is to not [<AutoOpen>] my library implementation and define a custom non-conflicting operator in modules where they might conflict. ex: 
let (>>>=) a b = MyModule.(>>=) a b